# Select values from a table which are not in another table in Django

Tags: django, model

Here are my models

```
class Paper(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  year = models.CharField(max_length=6)

class Rating(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  paper = models.ForeignKey(Paper)
  Rating = models.CharField(max_length=1)
```

Here is what I want to do

1. I want to retrieve all papers which are not rated. (I think it can be done using exclude(). But not sure how to do it.)
2. Retrieve all rated papers with its ratings so that it can be passed for rendering template

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You should read some documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a filter with the field lookup `__isnull` to check for the existence of the related item [as described here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

To get all instances of Paper that DO NOT have a Rating:

```
papers_without_ratings = Paper.objects.filter(rating__isnull=True)
```

To get all instances of Paper that have a Rating:

```
papers_with_ratings = Paper.objects.filter(rating__isnull=False).distinct()
```